# In A Course She Took from Gorsuch

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the pattern "*take a course from somebody*", as in this [example](http://www.npr.org/2017/03/20/520743555/former-law-student-gorsuch-told-class-women-manipulate-maternal-leave):

> A former law student of Judge Neil Gorsuch, President Trump's nominee for the U.S. Supreme Court, alleges that ***in a course she took from Gorsuch*** at the University of Colorado Law School last year ....

Is it standard English to write "take a course ***from*** somebody" instead of "take a course ***taught by*** somebody"?

Comment: Technically, it would describe a course Gorsuch was supposed to teach and the writer arranged to teach the course instead, and "taught by" would be the correct phrase.  However, "took from" is sometimes used in conversation like this.

Answer (score 1):

> in a course she took *from* Gorsuch

would be understood to mean the course was taught by Gorsuch, that he *offered* the course and she *took* it, in the same way that

> She took the book *from* her friend.

It might be more precise to say

> in a course she took *taught by* Gorsuch

Some might even say

> in a course she took *with* Gorsuch

which might be ambiguous since it might mean that both she and Gorsuch were students in the same course. However, with additional context might have the same meaning as your original phrase that Gorsuch taught the course.

> The university offered a course *with* Gorsuch *(as lecturer)*.